# Derivative of $\int_0^{x^2} \sec(t) \,dt$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do I derive this? I always get confused since there is $x$ and $t$ involved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FTC tells you that

$$F(x)=\int_0^x \sec(t) dt$$

has a derivative $F'(x)=\sec(x)$. Now you have $F(x^2)$, so you differentiate that using the chain rule.

Note that this only makes proper sense for $x^2<\pi/2$.

Answer (score 0):

Since you will face this kind of problem quite often in your studies, let me make it more general considering $$f(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(t) \, dt$$ The fundamental theorem of calculus tell that $$f(x)=f\big(b(x)\big) \,b'(x)-f\big(a(x)\big)\, a'(x)$$ The case you posted is simple since $a(x)=0$, $b(x)=x^2$, $a'(x)=0$, $b'(x)=2x$, $f(t)=\sec(t)$; so, replacing $$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^{x^2} \sec(t) \,dt=2x \sec(x^2)$$